# Unable to logout of Facebook using FB PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the FB PHP SDK to get a user's FB access token etc.

After I'm done getting all my info, I am attempting to logout the user, but it doesn't work. For debugging purposes, I'm doing this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => FB_APP_ID,
        'secret' => FB_SECRET
    ));
$params = array( 'next' => site_url('welcome/logout') );
$link = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params); // $params is optional. 
echo $link;
```

This gives me a link like this:

```
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fwelcome%2Flogout&access_token=xxxxxxxx
```

If I point my browser to that URL, I get redirected back to my callback URL, but immediately after, if I go to Facebook.com, I'm still logged in.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried using the JS SDK but that doesn't work because everything else is being done server side (using the PHP SDK). So, when I call `FB.logout()` using the JS SDK, it says `Logout called without access token`.

**EDIT**

I suppose before proceeding further, could someone confirm this:
When I follow the logout URL, does it actually log me out of Facebook, or just end the session between my app and the user?

If that is so, is there any way to completely Log out the user from Facebook? (I'm guessing no).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE: using the JS SDK, you can use both the JS SDK and the PHP SDK at the same time, interchangably now (and have been for about a year). SO if the JS method suits you better, I suggest you try that.

RE the "Edit": Yes, it completely logs you out of Facebook.

Now for the opening feature question. The scenario you desribe happens during development, but I've never pinpointed why. I think it's to do with the cookie being stored at the wrong domain (facebook stores what it thinks is the base domain, and if you fiddle with the base domain, or have two applications on the same base domain, the it gets those in a twist).

Clearing cookies sorts it out. Then make sure you don't manipulate domain in the settings in Facebook and it'll hopefully not reappear. (I say hopefully as I've never exactly pin-pointed the trigger, but I've never had it happen to a stable app once development has finished.)

Comment: I could not figure out how to pass an access token received from the PHP SDK to the JS SDK. However, if I do the login with the JS SDK (and then pass the token to a PHP script to get an extended token) that works fine, including the logout function. So, I just decided to go with the JS SDK. Thanks for the help anyways. (PS - I was developing directly on my web server, so it wasn't a dev environment)